# CakePHP 3 - Login Error - Call to a member function identify on boolean

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-3.0, identify

Hello I'm using CakePHP 3 to simple setup a site which some pages of it need user to login first.

It was fine when I put the `loadComponent('Auth', blablabla)` code in `initialize()` of `AppController.php`.

src\Controller\AdminController.php

```
...
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $admin = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($admin) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($admin);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error('Your username or password is incorrect.');
    }
}
...
```

src\Controller\AppController.php

```
...
public function initialize() {
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'Authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'userModel' => 'Admin',
                'Fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Admin',
            'action' => 'login',
        ]
    ]);

    $this->Auth->allow(['display']);
}
...
```

At this point, I needed to login in order to view all other pages of the site.
But I tried to put this same authentication setup in another controller called `JustController`, and after I logged in, a fetal error stated

> Call to a member function identify() on boolean

has been shown.

It should be possible to setup authentication in other controllers so that the site can have more than 1 set of login system instead of covering whole site by setting up in `AppController`, doesn't it?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you called AppController's initialize in AdminController?

Comment: @cjquinn Thanks you replying. Do you mean in `AdminController` 's `initialize()` ? It doesn't cause difference after I called it. But doesn't `AppController` 's `initialize()` be called as `AdminController` extends it? It's cool to have a friend replying, may I know your opinion that building two login schemes in CakePHP site? e.g. forum_user and panel_admin. You use the prefix thing?

Comment: Yes you're right if you haven't overloaded `AppController`'s `initialize()` in `AdminController` you shouldn't need to call it. I would use a role field in you need two login schemes, then you could use `isAuthorized()` to manage the different types of users. See http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#using-controllerauthorize

Comment: @cjquinn Thank you for your opinion. I found that I can load the `Auth` component in `beforeFilter()` instead of `initialize()`, and it works. Also inside the `breforeFilter()`, I can use `$this->request->params["prefix"]` to separate 2 login schemes.

Comment: Ace, thats good to know!